# Python Global Sensitivity Analysis using SALib for Stiff ODEs

Tags: ode, array-broadcasting, salib

I have used SALib previously to do GSA of system of ODEs.  I am trying to use it again, but now my ODEs are stiff.  Therefore, odeint() is failing and I am switching to solve_ivp().
Somehow I am having difficulty with this, and keep getting an error about broadcasting: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1000,100,2) into shape (200000,).  Would anyone be able to help me?

This is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol

# Define the stiff ODE model
def stiff_ode(t, y, k1, k2):
    dydt = [
        -k1 * y[0] + k2 * y[1],
        k1 * y[0] - k2 * y[1]
    ]
    return dydt

# Function to solve the stiff ODE
def solve_stiff_ode(params):
    t_span = (0, 10)
    y0 = [1, 0]  # Initial conditions
    solution = solve_ivp(stiff_ode, t_span, y0, args=params, t_eval=np.linspace(0, 10, 100), method='BDF')
    return solution.y

# Define parameter ranges
problem = {
    'num_vars': 2,
    'names': ['k1', 'k2'],
    'bounds': [[0.1, 1.0], [0.1, 1.0]]
}

# Generate parameter samples using Saltelli's method
param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 1000)

# Initialize an array to store the results
results = np.zeros((param_values.shape[0], 2, 100))

# Simulate the model for each set of parameters
for i, p in enumerate(param_values):
    solution = solve_stiff_ode(p)
    results[i, :, :] = solution

# Perform Sobol sensitivity analysis
Si = sobol.analyze(problem, results.reshape((-1, 100, 2)), print_to_console=True)
'''
```